# Configuring and Installing Open SSO

Tags: single-sign-on

I am trying SSO integration between sales force and open sso but i got struck in configuring Open SSO I followed [this link](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_SAML_on_Force.com) for config.

I have installed glass fish and I have started domain but I don't know how to config Open SSO.
Can anyone guide me?

I get the following error while deploying opensso.war file through glass fish server

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSP1007: Policy exception occurred when finishing WSDL parsing.. Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OpenSSO specifically, and not about Salesforce.

Comment: Manoj, if this is about configuring an SSO integration between Salesforce and OpenSSO can you please be more specific? Your question is at risk for being closed right now for being off-topic to the salesforce theme of this Stackexchange.

Comment: ya I am trying cofiguring an SSO integration between salesforce and open SSO